# OpenShift concurrent connections

Tags: cloud, openshift

According to OpenShift’s Knowledge Base, **max amount of concurrent connections** per gear is set at 10 requests and you can have a maximum of 16 gears. What if you want to provide a web service that needs to handle up to 5 million requests an hour (which is roughly 1150 per second)?

Answer (score 5):

I contacted **OpenShift Support** and they commented as below:

> The Bronze plan would be able to handle 256 concurrent connections (16 gears at 16 connections each = 256). However, with our Silver plan we're able to increase your maximum gear limit to fit your requirements.

**Note:** With scaling application 1 gear will be used up by database. So with Bronze plan you will be left with 15.

Answer (score 0):

I also contacted them for current status on this issue. According to OpenShift support reply,

> We do not exercise limiting concurrent connections to gears presently, so the actual limit will be defined by the resources use (number of gears and their sizes) and your code's efficiency.
>
> Note that there could be some limits implemented into cartridges however, e.g. the MySQL add-on cartridge will limit the concurrent connections to the database server per the my.cnf configuration.

Sep 19, 2016